# "В чём проблема – взять две пары?" Ставится ли тут тире?

Tags: тире

> В чём проблема – взять две пары?

Если правильно судить, то тире заменяет сказуемое в данном предложении, но что-то всё равно смущает.

Comment: Не смущает тире без пробелов? Оно же «заменяет сказуемое».

Comment: К сожалению, правила написания в интернете мне немного неизвестны.

Comment: "Немного неизвестны" - это как? В малой степени неизвестны, а в основном известны?

Answer (score 1):

В чём (заключается) проблема – взять две пары? (Или: Какая проблема – взять две пары?)

Это простое предложение, осложненное обособленным  инфинитивом с пояснительным значением (раскрывает значение местоимения *в чём* или *какая*).

Поэтому тире не заменяет сказуемое, а используется для обособления инфинитива.

Для сравнения: Проблема – взять две пары.

Здесь тире ставится между подлежащим и именной частью сказуемого, выраженного инфинитивом,  при отсутствии связки.

Answer (score 0):

1. Мы хотим спросить: проблема в том, чтобы взять две пары?

**В чем проблема? Взять две пары?** Здесь два предложения. Соединять их в БСП мне кажется неверным.

> В чем проблема-то? С квартирой, что ли? [Валентин Черных. Москва слезам не верит (1980)]

2. Мы хотим спросить: какую вы видите проблему в том, чтобы взять две пары?

**В чем (состоит) проблема взять две пары?**

Проблема (какая?) взять две пары. "Взять две пары" — несогласованное определение. Знаки препинания не нужны.